# Problem with jumping list elements with onMove (SwiftUI)

Tags: swiftui

I have implemented a SwiftUI list. When I drag and drop an element (with .onMove) one element disappears and a second later it appears at the expected position shown in the Screencast. The result is ok, but it looks not so good.
Here is the code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Data: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var number: Int = 0
    var text: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var myData: [Data] = []
    
    init() {
        _myData = State(initialValue: [
            Data(id: UUID(), text: "1111111"),
            Data(id: UUID(), text: "2222222"),
            Data(id: UUID(), text: "3333333"),
            Data(id: UUID(), text: "4444444"),
            Data(id: UUID(), text: "5555555"),
            Data(id: UUID(), text: "6666666")
        ])
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(0..<myData.count, id: \.self) { i in
                    Button("\(myData[i].text) (\(myData[i].number))") {
                        myData[i].number += 1
                    }
                }.onMove(perform: move)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func move(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
        myData.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
    }
    
}
```

[image: Reorder Problem]

Comment: I figured out that it happened only in preview mode on XCode. Your code works fine on the simulator. Tested on iPhone 14 iOS 16.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original code, the use of myData[i] to access elements within the @State variable may lead to some challenges, particularly in detecting changes within each Data object.

Here’s a revised version of your code that should improve the drag-and-drop behavior:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Data: Identifiable, Equatable {
    var id: UUID
    var number: Int = 0
    var text: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var myData: [Data] = []
    
    init() {
        _myData = State(initialValue: [
            Data(id: UUID(), text: "1111111"),
            Data(id: UUID(), text: "2222222"),
            Data(id: UUID(), text: "3333333"),
            Data(id: UUID(), text: "4444444"),
            Data(id: UUID(), text: "5555555"),
            Data(id: UUID(), text: "6666666")
        ])
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(myData) { data in
                    let i = myData.firstIndex(of: data)!
                    
                    
                    Button("\(myData[i].text) (\(myData[i].number))") {
                        myData[i].number += 1
                    }
                }
                .onMove(perform: move)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func move(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
        myData.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
    }
    
}
```

This revised code iterates directly over myData.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Many thanks. This is exactly what I am looking for. I didn't found the workaround for  getting the right index of the array element.